# Erro "Unable to instantiate activity" ao executar Activity

Tags: java, android

Meu aplicativo tem uma tela inicial, onde o usuário pode selecionar a tela de cadastro. Porém, é só eu por os `gets` que ele para de funcionar com esse erro abaixo, não chega a mostrar a activity de cadastro.

O erro é o seguinte:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.romulo.fateclins/com.example.romulo.fateclins.CadastroActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference

Ele aparece somente quando eu coloco os gets, dos campos na classe cadastro desta activity:

```
package com.example.romulo.fateclins;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static android.R.attr.button;
import static android.R.attr.duration;
import static android.R.attr.publicKey;
import static com.example.romulo.fateclins.R.layout.activity_cadastro;
import static com.example.romulo.fateclins.R.layout.activity_login;

public class CadastroActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Usuarios usuarios;
    private EditText editTextNome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextNome);
    private EditText editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    private EditText editTextCurso = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextCurso);
    private EditText editTextSemestre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSemestre);
    private EditText editTextRA = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextRA);
    private EditText editTextUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUsername);
    private EditText editTextSenha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSenha);


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cadastro);
        this.usuarios = new Usuarios();
        Button botaocadastrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCadastrar);
        botaocadastrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                cadastrar();

            }
        });
    }



    public void cadastrar (){


        this.usuarios.setNOME(this.editTextNome.getText().toString());
        this.usuarios.setEMAIL(this.editTextEmail.getText().toString());
        this.usuarios.setCURSO(this.editTextCurso.getText().toString());
        this.usuarios.setSEMESTRE(this.editTextSemestre.getText().toString());
        this.usuarios.setRA(this.editTextRA.getText().toString());
        this.usuarios.setUSERNARME(this.editTextUsername.getText().toString());
        this.usuarios.setPASSWORD_2(this.editTextSenha.getText().toString());
        this.usuarios.cadastrar();

        Toast.makeText(this,this.usuarios.get_mensagem(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (usuarios.is_status()){
            finish();
        } else{
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Embora você esteja iniciando os componentes, provavelmente o text de alguns deles está nulo. Aí, como você chama o toString direto sem verificar a nulidade pode ocasionar o NPE. Sugiro que você coloque nos sets algo como: (componente.getText() != null ? componente.getText().toString) : "". Não coloquei como resposta pois estou supondo que seja isso baseado no trecho de código que você colocou.

Comment: Olá, Giuliana, muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inicialize os EditText dentro do método OnCreate:

```
private Usuarios usuarios;
private EditText editTextNome;
private EditText editTextEmail;
private EditText editTextCurso;
private EditText editTextSemestre;
private EditText editTextRA;
private EditText editTextUsername;
private EditText editTextSenha;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cadastro);


    editTextNome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextNome);
    editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    editTextCurso = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextCurso);
    editTextSemestre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSemestre);
    editTextRA = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextRA);
    editTextUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUsername);
    editTextSenha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSenha);

    this.usuarios = new Usuarios();
    Button botaocadastrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCadastrar);
    botaocadastrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            cadastrar();

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Olá Kleiser, muito obrigado cara! Funcionou!